# How to execute javascript for each individual nested div displaying images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a JS script to execute solo within each nested div. I have class conflicts, and I am unable to figure out how to basically iterate the script through each div without conflicts.

I have tried using .each, running different loops, classing the divs, and more. I have tried numerous things unsuccessfully. I wish I had kept track of all the different methods, but I've been at this for hours and have been unsuccessful in finding the correct syntax. It's quite obvious, I need serious work when it comes to programming. I have HTML, CSS, and bootstrap down pretty well, but Javascript and jQuery, I have just begun learning.

```
<link href="Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/thumbs.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid maxW opaque padtop">
    <!-- Jumbotron -->
    <div class="jumbotron container-fluid">
        <div>
            <img src="jumbo.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--First Div Thumbnail Photo Block -->
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h3 class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">Photo Block 1</h3>
        <div>
            <img id="0" class="preview normal" src="" alt="" /><br />
            <img id="1" class="thumb normal" src="sumpic.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="preview(this)" />
            <img id="2" class="thumb normal" src="sumotherpic.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="preview(this)" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Second Div Thumbnail Photo Block -->
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h3 class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">Photo Block 2</h3>
        <div>
            <img id="0" class="preview normal" src="" alt="" /><br />
            <img id="1" class="thumb normal" src="sumotherpic1.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="preview(this)" />
            <img id="2" class="thumb normal" src="sumotherpic2.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="preview(this)" />
            <img id="3" class="thumb normal" src="sumotherpic3.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="preview(this)" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.preview {
  width: Auto;
  max-height: 600px;
}

.thumb {
  width: 205px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.normal {
  border: 3px solid #000000;
}

.selected {
  border: 3px solid #ff0000;
}
```

And the JavaScript code:

```
var lastImg = 1; //Set initial thumbnail and preview
document.getElementById(0).src = document.getElementById(lastImg).src;
document.getElementById(lastImg).className = "thumb selected";

function preview(img) {
    document.getElementById(lastImg).className = "thumb normal";
    img.className = "thumb selected";
    document.getElementById(0).src = img.src;
    lastImg = img.id
}
```

I think that's everything.

So what I'm aiming for is each div block to have the thumbs underneath and the mouse-dover image displayed above as the large displayed image. It works great so long as there is one single div. As soon as I add 2+ I run into what I'm assuming is class conflicts where only the first div displays the large image. It will display the large image that was last moused over in any of the divs. It is empty in all divs, except the first. The thumbs have no issues being displayed in each div. Thank you in advance for any help, and thank you for understanding I'm new to this and trying to learn.

Comment: What will `document.getElementById(0)` return? Try it using the developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your using pure Javascript, no jQuery. That's ok of course

The obvious error I'm seeing is id = 0 instead of "0"
Another thing is "className" youre using instead of set attribute class

I would recommend in general 2 things:
Using example cases, and F11 and opening the console

As per you code, I made small fixes to get you going, and to understand the next step. I think that you should define object vars for lastimg, "0" and img then make the code more readable and scalable

```
var lastImg = 1; //Set initial thumbnail and preview
document.getElementById("0").src = document.getElementById(lastImg).src;
document.getElementById(lastImg).setAttribute("class", "thumb selected");

function preview(img) {
    document.getElementById(lastImg).setAttribute("class", "thumb normal");
document.getElementById(img).setAttribute("class", "thumb selected");
    document.getElementById("0").getAttribute("src") = document.getElementById("img").getAttribute("src");
    lastImg = img;
  }
```